# JSON communication

Tags: c#, json

i've just started to plan a project. I'll have a server (windows service) that can talk to many clients (Mobile Phone apps). I'd like them to communicate using JSON-RPC.

There will only be a a maximum of 10 clients connecting (maybe at the same time)

Will i need a full blown http server and if so are there any examples that are leightweight?

thanks

Comment: What about good ol' IIS?

Comment: i'd prefer something a bit smaller that i can package with my app.

Comment: to package with what app? Client?

Comment: the server that will be running as a windows service.

Comment: IIS comes with windows and can handle any job you throw at it. Better this than changing your stack in the middle of the project, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `System.Net.HttpListener`? Its my favorite class whenever I want to create a lightweight server.

- Read the request (GET or POST)
- Deserialize the request (or get it from url)
- Do the work
- Serialize the result back

and a little bit multi-threading of course